# Selenium webdriver not working after converting .py to .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

So I wrote a web scraper program that uses selenium webdriver as the medium. The code and the webdriver runs fine as standalone or through the IDE. The problem is it only works fine as a .py file. Whenever I convert it to .exe using pyinstaller, the driver won't respond anymore. Any advice?

PS: I use Windows and I tried already both through the CMD and Powershell.

Answer (score -1):

when using --onefile **relative paths may not work.**

ex:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver.exe')
```

may not work.

so you might need to change the webdriver executable path in the code. Try the following code **or just put the location where you driver is located**. (import necessary modules)

```
def rightpath(wrongpath):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(base_path, wrongpath)

driver = webdriver.<Driver>(rightpath('<a relative path>'))
```

Comment: I tried this and the driver still won't respond.

Comment: https://github.com/Dakilang-Tamad/MSU-Gensan-SSO-Mini-Client

Comment: this is the link to my software. I just updated the main Home.py to my latest code. The driver is used in the login function and called in the S0 and S1 classes.